# Visual Studio Code new feature connect to Jupyter Notebook, it is possible to connect to JupyterHub as well?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

Looking at this article: [Visual Studio Working with remote Jupyter Notebook](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server), wondering and trying with JupyterHub API but was not able to make a connection from Visual Studio Code.

It is possible to open a remote session in a JupyterHub server?

Comment: Hi Luis, did you solve this issue? we are getting 403 forbidding despite including the correct token in the URI

Comment: Hi @LeoGallucci, no, according to VSCode team still on the backlog https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3954#issuecomment-506638541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VSCode team was implementing support of Jupyter Notebooks with the feature of local or remote Jupyter servers: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support
Also new feature allows you to pick already existing kernel from the environment, allowing you to share the kernel with the web client and VSCode, amazing!